# Proving that a modular function is the sum of a constant function and an additive function

Tags: functions

My lecture notes for submodularity states that a function is modular if and only if it is the sum of a constant
function and an additive function.

Proving that (sum of a constant function and additive function) $=>$ modular is easy, but I'm not sure how to prove the opposite direction. (A function is modular if it satisfies the condition of submodularity with equality).

Comment: Define (sub)modular, add (co)domains for your functions, etc. and you might have a better chance of getting a response.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of sets and a modular set function $f$ on it.

If $A$, $B$ and $A\cup B$ are all in $\mathcal{F}$ (also we need $\emptyset$ to be in $\mathcal{F}$ which is guaranteed if you assume $\mathcal{F}$ to be a ring of sets) and are disjoint, then by modularity $$f(A\cup B)+f(\emptyset)=f(A)+f(B)$$

Define $g=f-f(\emptyset)$. If $f(\emptyset)$ is finite then $f=g+f(\emptyset)$ and $g$ is modular; If $f(\emptyset)$ is infinite then bad things can happen.

Consider $X=\{x,y\}$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $f(\emptyset)=f(\{y\})=+\infty$ and $f(X)=f(\{x\})=0$. If either of $A$ or $B$ is $\emptyset$ or $X$, or if $A=B$, then $$f(A\cup B)+f(A\cap B)=f(A)+f(B)$$ holds trivially. The remaining case is $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{y\}$ and the equality also holds. Thus $f$ is modular but not additive, since to be additive $f$ is identically infinity or has null empty set.